# how to not copy code ? generic and non generic implementation - to use same body

Tags: c#, .net, generics, refactoring

please tell me how should i rework this code so it is not so much copy/paste? is there any way to call generic as nongeneric? should i pass `<object>` to generic and be happy with that? what is best solution ?

i have for example

```
public interface IHttpService
{
 Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, HttpContent content, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default);
 Task Post(string uri, HttpContent content, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default);
 }
```

so they have almost same but diferent implementation

```
 public async Task Post(string uri, HttpContent content, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
    request.Content = content;
    await sendRequest(request, timeOut, token);
}

public async Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, HttpContent content, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
    request.Content = content;
    return await sendRequest<T>(request, timeOut, token);
}


private async Task sendRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    try
    {
        using var requestCTS = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
        using var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(requestCTS.Token, token);
        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, linkedCts.Token);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {              
                var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(token);
                throw new Exception(error);             
        }     
}

private async Task<T> sendRequest<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    try
    {
        using var requestCTS = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
        using var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(requestCTS.Token, token);      
        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, linkedCts.Token);
        
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {      
                var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(token);
                throw new Exception(error);
            
        }
        return (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>())!;

}
```

---

update

```
private async Task<HttpContent> sendRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    try
    {
        using var requestCTS = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
        using var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(requestCTS.Token, token);
        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, linkedCts.Token);
     
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
             await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(token);
                throw new Exception(error);
            
        }

        return response.Content;

    }
    catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException)
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateToLogout(StaticStringHelper.LogoutPatch);
        return default(HttpContent)!;
    }
}
```

and when i use it like

```
 public async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);        
    return  await (await sendRequest(request, timeOut, token)).ReadFromJsonAsync<T>(cancellationToken: token);

}
```

i get

```
 microsoft.AspNetCore. Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot access a disposed object.
  Object name: 'System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent'.
System. ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent'.
 at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
 at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic "void" in c#. In some cases you can just use a generic with something like a int or bool as a meaningless value. In other cases you just have to suck it up and keep two implementations.

In this particular case the only difference seem to be `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>()`, so you should be able to refactor this to make all other code common. Since the content is disposed you need to use a delegate to inject the code that is different:

```
 public Task Post(string uri, HttpContent content, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
=> Post<int>(uri, content, c => Task.FromResult(0), timeOut , token);

public async Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, HttpContent content, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
=> Post(uri, content, ReadFromJson, timeOut , token)!;

private Task<T> ReadFromJson(HttpContent content) => content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();

private async Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, HttpContent content, Func<HttpContent, Task<T>> handleContent, int timeOut = 100, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
    request.Content = content;
        try
    {
        using var requestCTS = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
        using var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(requestCTS.Token, token);      
        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, linkedCts.Token);
        
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {      
                var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(token);
                throw new Exception(error);
            
        }
        return await handleContent(response.Content);
}
```

`c => Task.FromResult(0)` is just something to make the generic types fit, the '0' value never used anywhere.

Comment: please check my update - i did somethink like this but it throws errors - why?

Comment: @d00lar doh!, the error is because the httpContent is disposed when the response is disposed. I have updated the example to handle this.

Comment: hello again. if i may. is there any way for this to handle also nulabletypes ? if i want to post<person?> for example and this from controller will return null in body ? how to return null from this post and not get exeption on this content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>() Unhandled exception rendering component: The input does not contain any JSON

Comment: @d00lar well, you can check if the content is null or empty before trying to parse it. But generics tend to not play well with nullables, at least not without restricting the type to class or struct.

Comment: Please look here if You may - maybe it is bad way for doing this kind of stuff / i should simple avoid this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75768660/blazor-http-generic-client-what-is-proper-way-to-handle-nulable-type-like-this