# blazor http generic client what is proper way to handle nulable type like this?

Tags: c#, api, generics, blazor, nullable

I build some blazor app

and i  want to have HttpGet like

```
person? x = await _httpClient.Get<person?>("url");
```

So from api if i return person then i want x to be it `value`, if from api i return `NULL` want to x be `NULL`

How to do this properly?

i have some httpclient with get like for example

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri, int timeOut = 100)
{           
        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri), linkedCts.Token);
        return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
    }
}
```

but the compilator on this `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>()` says that possible `null` return

But still if I return `NULL` from api then it throws
`The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'`

so does i need it to change to be of `Task<T?>` so it may return `null`? what is right path here?

what is best approach for this ? or am I missing something and this is not right way ?

Thank You and regards!

Comment: The reason of the compiler message is that `ReadFromJsonAsync<T>()` returns a `T?`... so here you have to choice: change the return type to `Task<T?>` or make a `if` statement and eventually return `default(T)` if  `ReadFromJsonAsync<T>()` returns  `null`

Comment: and default(T) will be null if type is nulable then ? (i will be office monday / no way to check and curious now ;p)

Comment: You can examine the default value with a little bit of code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default In general objects have a default value of null, but other types may have different default. Value types also have defaults - zero for ints, false for bools, etc etc. Note that the documentation for ReadFromJsonAsync states that it return a `Task<Object>` so I'm not 100% sure that nullability of the type is problem. Ref: [readfromjsonasync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any call into a data pipeline - Server or API - you should consider returning a result object, not a T.  This solves the problem of returning a null, you always return a result object, and you can include status information, such as success/failure and a failure message.

Here's what I use:

```cs
public sealed record ItemQueryResult<TRecord> : IDataResult
{
    public TRecord? Item { get; init;} 
    public bool Successful { get; init; }
    public string Message { get; init; } = string.Empty;

    private ItemQueryResult() { }

    public static ItemQueryResult<TRecord> Success(TRecord Item, string? message = null)
        => new ItemQueryResult<TRecord> { Successful=true, Item= Item, Message= message ?? string.Empty };

    public static ItemQueryResult<TRecord> Failure(string message)
        => new ItemQueryResult<TRecord> { Message = message};
}
```

For the record a list query result looks like this:

```cs
public sealed record ListQueryResult<TRecord> : IDataResult
{
    public IEnumerable<TRecord> Items { get; init;} = Enumerable.Empty<TRecord>();  
    public bool Successful { get; init; }
    public string Message { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public long TotalCount { get; init; }

    private ListQueryResult() { }

    public static ListQueryResult<TRecord> Success(IEnumerable<TRecord> Items, long totalCount, string? message = null)
        => new ListQueryResult<TRecord> {Successful=true,  Items= Items, TotalCount = totalCount, Message= message ?? string.Empty };

    public static ListQueryResult<TRecord> Failure(string message)
        => new ListQueryResult<TRecord> { Message = message};
}
```

`IDataResult` provides a common interface for all results.

```cs
public interface IDataResult
{
    public bool Successful { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
}
```

Comment: thx i was thinking abiut similar solution using oneof library and have then bool and person - it is similar i belive ;) but is it possible to do as i wanted simple way?

Comment: No, because you either have to return something, or use http status codes.  Use something similar to what I've suggested.  It's provides a much more structured approach to the problem.